# Is there a way to download a lower quality image from a source uri?

Tags: react-native

I currently have a lot of images hosted on a website, and I get them with their respective URLs with React Native. But each image is very large, and sometimes, I only need small versions of the images. Is there a way to download a small version of the same image from the same URL?

Comment: Where are you downloading Image from? There are often urls for smaller images.

Comment: I uploaded them myself to imgur.

Comment: Check this out, you can specify height, width and other things
https://api.imgur.com/models/image

Comment: Interesting. Though due to time constraints, I already went with uploading a lot of smaller images instead. Maybe I can try it some other time

Comment: Yup makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

To download smaller image server has to implement the feature so that the client can send query or parameters like `width=100` & `height=100` to the server and get the requested image in response.

But if you want to resize the images without concerning about what server is giving. You can set your compression code on the client side and store/show image as you want.

You can use image resize libraries like [react-native-image-resizer](https://github.com/bamlab/react-native-image-resizer)